# How to add extra button to ion-nav-bar for a specific page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic. I have designed my UI as per ionic framework. In my app, for most of the pages, ion-nav-bar contains same buttons. But for some pages, I want to add extra buttons(ie., I don't want to remove existing common buttons on navbar, but I want to add an extra). I have been reading the docs of ion-nav-buttons, which tells that whatever view-specific button you provides, it'll replace existing buttons(which I don't want). The other alternative, I can think of is, create ion-nav-buttons in child view, which contains all common buttons as well as view specific buttons, which I don't think is a better solution(since it involves duplicating same markup and thus this solution doesn't scale well).

Is there any workaround for this situation ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Which ionic version you are talking about, if it's IonicV1 then you can provide data to route (in config method)  and show and hide that button on the basis of value. This can an approach I am not sure if this is best approach.

Comment: I am using ionicv2

Comment: @Squeakasaur, Actually my POC have become too big, to be shared on codepen. So, Can you just give me an idea or any reference or example ?

Answer (score 0):

at that particular page.html use something like below

```
 ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>DashBoard</ion-title>
    <button ion-button class="logout_btn">extra button</button>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```